# How to make windows steal focus when links are opened

Tags: 15.10, browser, focus

When opening a web URL, the focus does not move to the browser window. How can we achieve this?
I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this using Compiz config settings manager

1. Install ccsm:

   ```
   sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. **General Options > Focus & Raise Behaviour**
3. Set **Focus Prevention Level** to OFF

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this also.

It appears it is a reported bug in Unity.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/772007